# Logstash - csv output headers

Tags: ruby, csv, logstash

I'm trying to request database with [logstash jdbc plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-parameters) and returns a csv output file with headers with [logstash csv plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-autogenerate_column_names).

I spent a lot of time on logstash documentation but I'm still missing a point.

With the following logstash configuration, the results give me a file with headers for each row. I couldn't find a way to add the headers for only the first row in the logstash configuration.

Helps very much appreciated.

## Output file

```
_object$id;_object$name;_object$type;nb_surveys;csat_score
2;Jeff Karas;Agent;2;2  
_object$id;_object$name;_object$type;nb_surveys;csat_score
3;John Lafer;Agent;2;2;2;2;$2;2
_object$id;_object$name;_object$type;nb_surveys;csat_score
4;Michele Fisher;Agent;2;2
_object$id;_object$name;_object$type;nb_surveys;csat_score
5;Chad Hendren;Agent;2;78
```

## file: simple-out.conf

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/tmp/drivers/postgresql/postgresql_jdbc.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement_filepath => "query.sql"
    }
}
output {
    csv {
        fields => ["_object$id","_object$name","_object$type","nb_surveys","csat_score"]
        path => "output/%{team}/output-%{team}.%{+yyyy.MM.dd}.csv"
        csv_options => {
        "write_headers" => true
        "headers" =>["_object$id","_object$name","_object$type","nb_surveys","csat_score"]
        "col_sep" => ";"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you set write_headers to false?

Comment: I guess this is impossible in general, since logstash expects non-relational dataset, where the columns for each row might differ. Whether you are concerned that fields are same, I would go with old good `Array#uniq` on the result. The latter will give you what you want in literally 10 symbols of code.

Comment: @JLB if I set write_headers, my output file returns no headers at all, not even in the first row.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the suggestion but I would like to use Logstash logic as much as possible to include different inputs in future steps. If it is impossible, I would rather use a script adding the headers before processing my output file. Thanks.

Comment: What if you a) turn headers off and b) make the first row of data = to the column names you want?

Comment: "make the first row of data = to the column names you want?" could you post an example for this please @JLB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you are getting multiple headers in the output is because Logstash has no concept of global/shared state between events, each item is handled in isolation so every time the CSV output plugin runs it behaves like the first one and writes the headers.

I had the same issue and found a solution using the [init](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html#plugins-filters-ruby-init) option of the ruby filter to execute some code at logstash startup-time.

Here is an example logstash config:

```
# csv-headers.conf

input {
    stdin {}
}
filter {
    ruby {
        init => "
            begin
                @@csv_file    = 'output.csv'
                @@csv_headers = ['A','B','C']
                if File.zero?(@@csv_file) || !File.exist?(@@csv_file)
                    CSV.open(@@csv_file, 'w') do |csv|
                        csv << @@csv_headers
                    end
                end
            end
        "
        code => "
            begin
                event['@metadata']['csv_file']    = @@csv_file
                event['@metadata']['csv_headers'] = @@csv_headers
            end
        "
    }
    csv {
        columns => ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
}
output {
    csv {
        fields => ["a", "b", "c"]
        path   => "%{[@metadata][csv_file]}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug {
            metadata => true
        }
    }
}
```

If you run Logstash with that config:

```
echo "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9" | ./bin/logstash -f csv-headers.conf
```

You will get an `output.csv` file with this content:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

This is also thread-safe because it runs the code on startup only, so you can use multiple workers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You made my day! Thank you very much @xmarcos .. Really helps a lot with your example.

Comment: If you are on latest version of the Elasticsearch then you need to update ruby code as shown here otherwise it will throw error and just put headers only in file. 
`code => "begin 
event.set('[@metadata][csv_file]', @@csv_file)
                event.set('[@metadata][csv_headers]', @@csv_headers)
            end"`

Answer (score 0):

I am using dynamic file names that leverage the date of the event (index-YYYY-MM-DD.csv) so writing the headers on pipeline start was not a viable option for me.

Instead, I allowed the duplicate headers to be written and set up a cron job to run every few minutes and remove all duplicate rows and write the result back into the same file.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
 for filename in /tmp/logstash/*.csv; do awk '!v[$1]++' $filename > $filename.tmp && mv -f $filename.tmp $filename; done
```

NOTE: This is only tested on an instance where I am pulling a couple hundred MB of data - this may not be a viable option if your data pipeline is ingesting GB per minute.